# Cordova missing packages to build for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to build a empty Cordova application and a existing one for the platform ubuntu on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit). But when I am trying to build it, I am getting that I miss some packages:

```
Error: missing packages click cmake libicu-dev pkg-config devscripts qtbase5-dev qtchooser qtdeclarative5-dev qtfeedback5-dev qtlocation5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev qtpim5-dev libqt5sensors5-dev qtsystems5-dev
```

After that I am getting the following message:

```
Install missing packages? (Yn)>
```

Then I accept to install and let it run a few times for hours but nothing happened, only a blinking cube on the next line.
How can I fix that it will install the packages?

I already installed every package with apt but that is not working, it still give's the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just install the missing packages manually:

```
sudo apt-get install click cmake libicu-dev pkg-config devscripts qtbase5-dev qtchooser qtdeclarative5-dev qtfeedback5-dev qtlocation5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev qtpim5-dev libqt5sensors5-dev qtsystems5-dev
```

then run the cordova build command again

Comment: Thanks this is working great now, still strange beacuse I already tried to install the packages by hand, but I think I missed some.

Answer (score 2):

This is a genuine issue in Apache cordova itself. An issue has been logged in their official bug tracking system - [CB-11333](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11333)

The issue is raised yesterday and you may have to wait for the fix. Hope it helps.